# Very weird glitch with twitter bootstrap and glyphicons and Spring web app

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I'm using twitter bootstrap for the design of my web app. I'm using Spring boot, Spring MVC, and Spring Security for the backend. I'm also using thymeleaf for the view. I have glyphicons on my home page and they don't show up when I first open my app, it just shows an empty box with a border, where they glyphicons are supposed to be.  When I log in to my app, and only when I log in and it redirects me to the home page, the screen just shows a list of glyphicons and the url points to `http://localhost:8080/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf`, and then when I manually type in the url to send me to the home page the glyphicons show up.  I have no idea why this could be happening and I don't know why logging in causes something to happen to the glyphicons, I would think they would be unrelated events.  If anyone has any ideas as to why this could be happening, and could let me know that would be super helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that this resource is only accessible once you are  authenticated?

If that is the case you might load an empty response (or a failed attempt) during the login screen and once the ttf is loaded it's taken from the browser cache, which is still empty.

Comment: Wow, thanks, in the spring security config file I had to allow this url `fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf` to be accessed by everyone.

Comment: Glad i could help. You should probably open everything behind `fonts`. There might be other resources too :)

Comment: There was, and I did that as well.  Everything works fine now, thanks.